# The compiler is showing error Kotlin: Variable 'mAdapter' must be initialized

Tags: kotlin

code：

```
private val mAdapter: BaseAdapter = createAdapter(R.id.adapter) { listPosition: Int ->
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(listPosition)
}
```

How can I remove this warning. Like "?" or "!!".

Answer (score 1):

You can reorganize your code this way

```
private val mAdapter: BaseAdapter by lazy {
    createAdapter(R.id.adapter) { listPosition: Int ->
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(listPosition)
    }
}
```

Or change `val` to `lateinit var` if possible

```
private lateinit var mAdapter: BaseAdapter

init {
    mAdapter = createAdapter(R.id.adapter) { listPosition: Int ->
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(listPosition)
    }
}
```